# Is it grammatically and meaningfully current to say that "Times to see your exam papers will be on "

Tags: phrase-meaning, grammaticality

Is it grammatically and meaningfully current to say that

> Times to see your exam papers will be on ...

I mean the phrase "Times to see .." is kind of scratching my ear for some reason, so is there any grammatically or meaningfully wrong usage in this sentence ?

Edit: I mean for me the usage of "Times to see" is kind of a wrong similar to usage of "like" when we state similar thing.

Comment: I think you need to give more context for the quote. I expect an exam paper to be revealed to the candidates at the start of the exam. I do not expect them to be able to see it before the exam because that would allow them time to prepare for the actual questions. On the other hand, it might be after the exam has been marked and is allowing the candidates one or more time periods when they can see how their paper was marked (possibly as a discussion with their teacher).

Comment: @AdrianHHH It is for paper review :).Plus, I'm just interested in the usage of "Times to see".

Comment: @AdrianHHH See my edit also.

Comment: The phrase works fine in something like *"Times to see the animals being fed are every morning between 10 and 11am." (Plus the implied they are also fed in the evening when the place is closed to the public.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES.

> Times to see your exam papers will be on Tuesday and Thursday at Noon and 3pm.

-or-

> Times to see your exam papers will be **at** Noon and 3pm.

This construction I would expect to be more often written, such as posted on a board, rather than spoken.

Answer (score 0):

> Times to see your exam papers will be *at* X.

*At* is used with times, not *on*.

> Times to see your exam papers will be at 2pm, 3pm and 5pm.

Note you use *on* with days if that's  what you meant.

> Days to see your exame papers will be Monday, Tuesday, and Wednesday.

Comment: *Times to see your exam papers will be [posted] **on** the school notice board tomorrow morning.*